# how to sort label value from high to low score?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

i have 4 labels in my view holding scores

how can i sort that scores from highest to lowest score ?

because i want to change the color of the highest score to green and the lowest to red and the 2 scores in between yellow

i can use this code

```
float a = ([label1.text floatValue]);
float b = ([label2.text floatValue]);
if (a > b) { //do something }
```

but i have 4 labels and i don't want to write the long code for it checking each label if its bigger than the others or smaller.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make a sorted array of labels:

```
NSArray *labels = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:label1, label2, label3, label4, nil];
NSArray *sortedLabels = [labels sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(UILabel *a, UILabel *b) {
    float first = [a.text floatValue];
    float second = [b.text floatValue];
    if (first < second) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (first > second) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}];
```

Then to get the rank of a label, just do

```
NSUInteger rank = [sortedLabels indexOfObject:aLabel];
// rank goes from 0 to 3, with 0 corresponding to lowest value and 3 corresponding to  highest value
```